# calling another function in another action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, store, reduce, thunk

> 

```
import Axios from "axios";

export const ChangeTodoCount = (newCount) => {
  return {
    type: "CHANGE_TODO_COUNT",
    payload: newCount,
  };
};

export const FetchToDo = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:2000/todo").then((response) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "GET_TODO",
        payload: response.data,
      });
      dispatch({
        type: "CHANGE_TODO_COUNT",
        payload: response.data.length,
      });
    });
  };
};

export const DeleteItem = (id) => {
  Axios.delete("http://localhost:2000/todo/" + id).then({ FetchToDo });
};
```

I'm trying to call `FetchToDo` after i run `DeleteItem`.

how would i need to add the `FetchToDo` to do that?
Right now, when i clicked on the delete button, the list is deleted but i have to refresh the page to re-fetch the list.

Comment: try `Axios.delete("http://localhost:2000/todo/" + id).then(() => FetchToDo());`

Comment: it still does the same thing, it deleted data on my list but i still have to refresh the page to refresh the list

Answer (score 0):

```
`export const DeleteItem = (id) => {Axios.delete("http://localhost:2000/todo/" + id).then(()=>FetchToDo())};`
```